# Why Google sign in result is null when application is uploaded to PlayStore

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-services

When I test my application's app_release.apk on Android phones **Google Sign in result is true**. But when I upload it on playstore or update it's version and download it from their playstore, **Google Handle sign in result is null**, there by not allowing me to authenticate the users using Google accounts.
Does any one knows where I am screwing? Any Idea about this problem, please help me.

BaseActivity.java
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
protected String mProvider, mEncodedEmail;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final String TAG = "BaseActivity";
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener, mAuthListener1;
protected Firebase mFirebaseRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    /* Setup the Google API object to allow Google logins */
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    /**
     * Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
     * options specified by gso.
     */
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();



           /*In the onCreate() method, initialize he FirebaseAuth instance and the AuthStateListner
    * method so we can track the user signs in or out*/

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
   /* mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
               takeUserToLoginScreenOnUnAuth();
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };*/

    /**
     * Getting mProvider and mEncodedEmail from SharedPreferences
     */
    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BaseActivity.this);
    /* Get mEncodedEmail and mProvider from SharedPreferences, use null as default value */
    mEncodedEmail = sp.getString(Constants.KEY_ENCODED_EMAIL, null);
    mProvider = sp.getString(Constants.KEY_PROVIDER, null);
```

LoginActivity.java

```
   GoogleSignInAccount mGoogleAccount;
    private final Context mContext = this;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String idToken;
    private String name, email, phoneNumber;
    private String photo;
    private String circle;
    private String preferredCircle;
    private Uri photoUri;
    private String mEncodedEmail;
    private boolean isSelectSpinner1 = false, isSelectSpinner2 = false;
    MaterialSpinner spinner1, spinner2;

    //private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //STORAGE DATABASE Variables
    private StorageReference mImageStorage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
}


  */
    public void initializeScreen() {
       /* Setup Google Sign In */
        setupGoogleSignIn();
    }

    /**
     * Show error toast to users
     */
    private void showErrorToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    /**
     * GOOGLE SIGN IN CODE
     *
     * This code is mostly boiler plate from
     * https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
     * and
     * https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java
     *
     * The big picture steps are:
     * 1. User clicks the sign in with Google button
     * 2. An intent is started for sign in.
     *      - If the connection fails it is caught in the onConnectionFailed callback
     *      - If it finishes, onActivityResult is called with the correct request code.
     * 3. If the sign in was successful, set the mGoogleAccount to the current account and
     * then call get GoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin
     * 4. getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin launches an AsyncTask to get an OAuth2 token from Google.
     * 5. Once this token is retrieved it is available to you in the onPostExecute method of
     * the AsyncTask. **This is the token required by Firebase**
     */


    /* Sets up the Google Sign In Button : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton */
    private void setupGoogleSignIn() {
        Button signInButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_with_google);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!isSelectSpinner1 && circle == null){
                    spinner1.setError("Please select your current Circle(CITY) in which you are posted");
                }
                else if(!isSelectSpinner2 && preferredCircle == null ) {
                    spinner2.setError("Please select your preferred Circle in which you want to work or move");

                }else{
                    onSignInGooglePressed(v);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Sign in with Google plus when user clicks "Sign in with Google" textView (button)
     */
    public void onSignInGooglePressed(View view) {

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
        Log.d(TAG, "signInGooglePressed");
      //  mAuthProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        /* Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...); */
        if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
    /**
     * This callback is triggered when any startActivityForResult finishes. The requestCode maps to
     * the value passed into startActivityForResult.
     */

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            /* Signed in successfully, get the OAuth token */
            mGoogleAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(mGoogleAccount);
            //getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin();

        } else {
            if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
                showErrorToast("The sign in was cancelled. Make sure you're connected to the internet and try again.");
            } else {
               // showErrorToast("Error handling the sign in: " + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
            }
           // mAuthProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I have also checked my google-services.json file my package name is same as in my project.

Comment: Do you have some code to show? How do you sign in user?

Comment: yes i have uploaded my code

Comment: can u update your question with error logs as well

Comment: no their are no error logs. or may be I dont know how to generate them.

Comment: Sir, the code is working fine when I manually add my final apk file in my phone i.e. Google authentication works. But after uploading the same final apk file on play store. Google SIgn In result returns null i.e. it doesnt authenticate the user

Comment: handlsignInResult is Null after uploading the same apk on play store

Answer (score 0):

Make sure sha1 keys are same in both firebase console and andeoid developer console. Also link the project in firebase console by going to settings linking tab i.e. the package name should be present.